# How Can I Stop Virgin Media Hub 3.0 From Interfering with my FTPS Server

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, ftps

I have an FTPS server (using VSFTPD) working on a Raspberry Pi. Since I switched to a Virgin Media 3.0 hub, I have been unable to successfully connect specifically with the FTPS server. After a lot of searching I found [this page](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Malicious_routers.2C_firewalls_and_data_sabotage) on the Filezilla wiki and I'm certain that this is the issue. Now I need to work out which settings I need to change to get the router to play nice with my server. Does anyone with the same router have any suggestions? Also please let me know if there is any more information I need to provide.

For the sake of completion, this is the result I get when trying to connect to my server through ftptest.net:

```
Status: Resolving address of my.server.com
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx
Warning: The entered address does not resolve to an IPv6 address.
Status: Connected, waiting for welcome message...
Reply: 220 [Welcome message]
Command: CLNT https://ftptest.net on behalf of xx.xx.xx.xx
Reply: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
Command: AUTH TLS
Reply: 234 Proceed with negotiation.
Status: Performing TLS handshake...
Status: TLS handshake successful, verifying certificate...
Status: Received 1 certificates from server.
Status: cert[0]: subject='CN=my.server.com' issuer='CN=my.server.com'
Command: USER incoming
Reply: 331 Please specify the password.
Command: PASS ***************************************
Reply: 230 Login successful.
Command: SYST
Reply: 215 UNIX Type: L8
Command: FEAT
Reply: 211-Features:
Reply: AUTH TLS
Reply: EPRT
Reply: EPSV
Reply: MDTM
Reply: PASV
Reply: PBSZ
Reply: PROT
Reply: REST STREAM
Reply: SIZE
Reply: TVFS
Reply: 211 End
Warning: The server does not indicate MLSD support. MLSD uses a well-specified listing format. Without MLSD, directory listings have to be obtained using LIST which uses an unspecified output format.
Command: PBSZ 0
Reply: 200 PBSZ set to 0.
Command: PROT P
Reply: 200 PROT now Private.
Command: PWD
Reply: 257 "/" is the current directory
Status: Current path is /
Command: TYPE I
Reply: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command: PASV
Reply: 227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xx,xx,39,110).
Error: Server returned unroutable private IP address in PASV reply
```

EDIT: I tried adding the `pasv_address`, `pasv_min_port` and `pasv_max_port` fields to my VSFTPD config and this was the last 2 lines of the result I got from ftptest.net: (All the other lines were the same)

```
Reply: 227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,39,112).
Error: Server returned broadcast address in PASV reply
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually have the exact opposite problem.

Usually FTP happens to work only *because* the router tampers with such things as PASV responses, substituting its own public IP address in place of your server's private address, or adding temporary port-forwarding rules for the data connection about to be established.

When you use FTPS and the control channel is encrypted, the router's FTP helper *cannot* see or alter the responses anymore, which means your clients see exactly what your server sends – even if it happens to be wrong. And because the router no longer knows when a data connection is about to be opened, it won't be able to update its firewall rules to allow this.

Usually FTP daemons have a configuration setting to change the address advertised in PASV responses, as well as a way to limit the PASV listening ports to a small range that can be manually forwarded to the server.

For VSFTPD you will need to set `pasv_address=` to your router's public IP address, then define a port range with `pasv_min/max_port=`. Your router needs to be configured to forward all TCP ports within that range to the FTPS server.

Comment: I tried the steps which you suggested but did not get much of a different result. The differences I could see from running ftptest was the last 2 lines now reads: 
`Reply: 227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,39,112).` (Before the first four numbers showed the pi's local ip address)
`Error: Server returned broadcast address in PASV reply`

Comment: @Limisios it sounds like you did not correctly set `pasv_address`.  Double-check the setting, make sure it is assigned your public IP address. `pasv_address=1.2.3.4` for example, but with your IP.

Comment: @Limisios or you may be encountering [this bug](https://serverfault.com/questions/821025/vsftpd-passive-reply-with-0-0-0-0-address-even-with-correct-pasv-address)

Answer (score 1):

I used the [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/821025/vsftpd-passive-reply-with-0-0-0-0-address-even-with-correct-pasv-address) that @kicken mentioned in their comment and that sorted out the problem. I think both that answer and @user1686's answer helped solve the problem.